# Magento 2: Cant get custom attribute when configured in catalog_attributes.xml file for mincart

Tags: magento2, catalog, custom-attributes, mini-cart

I need to get a custom attribute value to Min cart, But I am missing some thing on the catalog_attributes.xml to get the attribute value.

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
        <plugin name="Tech_mincart_Product_attribute" type="Tech\ConfigProductDynamicName\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

catalog_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="pcb_master"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

DefaultItem.php

```
<?php

namespace Tech\ConfigProductDynamicName\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData;

class DefaultItem
{

    public function aroundGetItemData(
            \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem $subject,
            \Closure $proceed,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item
    ) {
        $data = $proceed($item);
        $result['pcb_master'] = $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('pcb_master');


        return \array_merge($result,$data);
    }


}
```

View/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="itemRenderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                    <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                    <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Tech_ConfigProductDynamicName/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="item.image" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/image</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/product/image</item>
                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">itemImage</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Template/minicart/item/default.html

```
<div class="product-item-details" >
    <strong class="product-item-name" >
    <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
    <p data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"> </p>
     <input data-bind="value: pcb_master"
            type="text"
            class="pcb_master" />
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
     <!-- ko text: product_name --<!-- /ko -- >
    <!-- /ko -- >
    </strong>
```

I am not getting the custom attribute pcb_master in DefaultItem.php at

```
$result['pcb_master'] = $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('pcb_master');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the code

`$result['pcb_master'] = $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('pcb_master');`

Please do some changes

- `Do an indexing and cache flush.`
- `$result['pcb_master'] = $item->getProduct()->getData('pcb_master');`

Comment: " getData('pcb_master')" works, Now I can get the Custom Attribute . I referred this Blog https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/get-a-product-attribute-in-mini-cart-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

I got two Solution to achieve this.

**First Solution:**

Use `getData('pcb_master')` instard of `getAttributeText('pcb_master')`

From

> $result['pcb_master'] =
>   $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('pcb_master');

To

> $result['pcb_master'] = $item->getProduct()->getData('pcb_master');

**Second Solution:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
$result['pcb_master'] = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('pcb_master')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

I am using the First one, I am not sure the second one is the right way, But it works.

I Referred this blog https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/get-a-product-attribute-in-mini-cart-magento-2/